# Difference between "downvote" and "downvoted"?

Tags: support, down-votes

What is the difference between "downvote" and "downvoted"? Here is a screen shot from the Reputation sub-screen on the User tab:

[image: downvote vs downvoted]

Comment: Thou shalt both mete out and receive judgement.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for pointing out the relevant answer. Note that if you do a search on "downvote versus downvoted" as I did, that answer does not come up.

Comment: Don't sweat it; your question can now serve as a way-sign to the other post.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you downvote an answer, you lose one rep point. This displays in your profile (only to you!) as **downvoted**

When one of your posts is downvoted by someone else, you lose two reputation. This displays in your profile (to everyone) as **downvote**

The wording is subtle, and could possibly be improved. As it is, it's just something you learn by association with the action that triggered it.

Comment: I love that you use the opposing version both times when explaining the terms. "When you downvote, it shows *downvoted*. When a post is downvoted, it shows *downvote*."

Answer (score 6):

You have "downvoted" an answer (hence the -1)

A post of your got a "downvote" (hence the -2).

Comment: There's no inherent reason the words couldn't be used the other way around, though: "Your post was 'downvoted'"/"You cast a 'downvote'".